# Lower bound for $\| (I+A)^{-1} - (I+B)^{-1}\|$ where $A, B \ge 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, upper-lower-bounds, positive-semidefinite

Given two positive semi-definite matrices $A,B \ge 0$, I am interested in finding a lower bound for the operator norm:

$$
\| (I+A)^{-1} - (I+B)^{-1}\|.
$$

So far I have only been able to find an upper bound, namely

$$
\| (I+A)^{-1} - (I+B)^{-1}\| \le \| B-A\|
$$
which follows by noting that
$$
(I+A)^{-1} - (I+B)^{-1} = (I+A)^{-1}(B-A)(I+B)^{-1}
$$
and that $\| (I+A)^{-1} \| \le 1$ since $A \ge 0$ and similarly for the term involving $B$. I am stuck on finding a good lower bound though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your trick already gives you a lower bound. Since the operator norm is submultiplicative,
\begin{aligned}
&\quad\,\|I+A\|\|(I+A)^{-1}(B-A)(I+B)^{-1}\|\|I+B\|\\
&\ge\|(I+A)(I+A)^{-1}(B-A)(I+B)^{-1}(I+B)\|\\
&=\|B-A\|.
\end{aligned}
Therefore
\begin{aligned}
\|(I+A)^{-1}(B-A)(I+B)^{-1}\|
\ge\frac{\|B-A\|}{\|I+A\|\|I+B\|}
=\frac{\|B-A\|}{(1+\|A\|)(1+\|B\|)}.
\end{aligned}